# How do I break up Point(x=,y=) values returned from pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen()

Tags: python, pyautogui

How do I separate X values into an array with the x component and an `array` with the y component so I can use them separately?

```
pyautogui,locateCenterOnScreen(img.PNG,confidence=0.5)

returns Point(x=2140, y=1163)
```

Comment: It returns a `Point`. Index with `point[0]`, `point[1]` or `point.x`,`point.y`. There are examples in [the docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html)

Comment: Are you sure you want a list of x coordinates and a separate list of y coordinates? Wouldn't it be easier to work with one list of points?